# Dell 1545 running Windows 7 home premium 64bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update, updates, attributes

I'm using Windows update to download and install Windows 10. After completely downloading and beginning to install, it failed with error code `80070490`.

I looked up code did as instructed - downloaded the system update readiness tool, installed, pressed OK, attempted to finish the installation of Windows 10. I then received error code `80246005`. Looked it up tried to do as instructed using command prompt , type `attrib -h -s -r c:\windows\system32\catroot2`. My computer says (`attrib-h-s-r`) isn't recognized as internal or external command. I'm not completely computer illiterate but I don't know a lot still. Any idea?

Comment: @Unity_Computers please don't suggest edits that remove syntax errors from questions. You invalidate the question by doing this.

Comment: @Dave M Please don't approve edits that remove syntax errors from questions. You invalidate the question by doing this.

Comment: @Jakuje Please don't approve edits that remove syntax errors from questions. You invalidate the question by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

The error `80070490` means file not found ( `ERROR_NOT_FOUND - Element not found.`) and `80246005` means a network connection error (`WU_E_DM_NONETWORK - A download manager operation could not be completed because the network connection was unavailable.`).

The attrib command failed because you missed a space before the `-`.

Download the [Windows 10 Home ISO from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/techbench), use a ISO mounting tool to mount the ISO as DVD drive, go to the virtual DVD drive, double click on `setup.exe` and select Upgrade with the option you like (keep nothing, keep settings or keep all settings and installed applications).

Comment: ok, nice to hear this. click on the green button to accept the reply as answer.